# Distinguish Between Primary and Secondary Nodes in VMWare

Tags: powershell, vmware

I'm writing some powershell to gather data from our vSphere clusters. We have some VMs paired as Windows/SQL failover clusters, and I only want to gather data from the primary nodes. Is there a way in the VMWare powershell CLI to distinguish between then primary and secondary? I've looked through the exteneded properties of the VMs and haven't found anything, but thought maybe I'd missed it.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question is, how do you define which is the primary node, and which is the secondary node? From VMWare/CLI perspective, there is no "hardware"/"virtual hardware" level difference the only thing that would be different would be networking, and who owns the "Primary" IP Address.

Using VMWare PowerShell CLI module, it would look like:

```
Get-Module VMware.VimAutomation.Core
$cred = Get-Credential
Connect-VIServer -Server VC01 -Credential $cred

$computer = Get-VM -Name 'NODE01'
$IpAddresses = $computer.Guest.IPAddress
```

You end up having to visit each machine and pull a list of IP addresses, and then you will have iterate through to match up primary IP addresses, etc. This is a lot of work, and, in MHO, not the best way to find primary Node. The best way is to query the *actual* Failover Cluster to tell you what is the primary node using the [`FailoverClusters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/failoverclusters/?view=win10-ps) PowerShell Module:

```
Import-Module FailoverClusters
Get-Cluster -Name CLUSTER | Get-ClusterGroup

Name              OwnerNode  State
----              ---------  -----
Available Storage NODE01     Offline
Cluster Group     NODE01     Online
SQL01             NODE02     Online
```

Comment: your second suggestion should work, thanks for the response!